# No database selected. lesson bookings' unsuccessful entry : No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I get this error on `booking.php`

> bookings'unsuccessful entry: No database selected

I also have a `db_connect.php`

```
<?php

$dbname = "mysql:dbname=lessonbookings";
try{
    $db = new PDO($dbname,'root','');
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo 'connection error: ' . $ex->getMessage();
    }
?>
)
```

I get this error message and I double/tripled checked my database name. I cant figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Please try avoid database names with spaces. Choose lessonbookings or lesson_bookings instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space before lesson bookings

Comment: now i have the message: "          unsuccesfull entry: No database selected                   "

Comment: Try the answer of Y.Hermes, that is the good manner to instantiate a new PDO database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$host = "your host name"; //Add your Host Name (probably localhost)
$db = "lesson bookings";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $err) {
        echo "Error: ".$err->getMessage()."<br/>";
        die();
    }
```